# Should UUID be passed in or generated on construction of POJO?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, uuid

When creating a POJO it is bad practice to set any attributes in the constructor without passing them in because of dependency injection.

If you are setting one of the fields to a UUID value is this acceptable to be generated and set on construction? Or should it be passed in through the constructor?

Or is there a general pattern used for this?

Comment: This depends on a way how you generate these UUIDs. If you generate them with some factory that is not accessible from inside POJO, you choose passing them in constructor. If you just call UUID.randomUUID, it does not matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would definitely have a constructor that accepts a UUID for the reasons you already outlined. (And testing.)

However I would also add a static factory method that only accepts the values you really want to set externally in regular code. So something like this:

```
public class Foo {
    private final UUID id;
    private final Bar bar;

    Foo(UUID id, Bar bar) {
      this.id = id;
      this.bar = bar;
    }

    public static Foo create(Bar bar) {
        return new Foo(UUID.randomUUID(), bar);
    }
 }
```

*I specified the constructor as package-private, which is permissive enough for testing (if you happen to need it), and only leaves one publicly visible way to create instances of the class.*

Comment: upvoted for the factory, but why would you have a constructor there for testing?

Comment: @MrWiggles That depends on what my class does, but as an example, I want to test what happens when two beans have the same id.

Comment: That would make sense if you're using something else for IDs, but this is specifically a UUID so collisions /shouldn't/ be happening.  If you want to know what happens /outside/ of this class then using the same instance more than once would suffice.

Comment: @MrWiggles Of course writing a test purely for type 4 UUID collisions in the generating code is mad. But if your class is `Serializable`, suddenly collisions are a real possibility, either by accident or out of malice. Another possible reason is that you simply want your tests to be repeatable, which is a good idea in general. Or maybe the id will appear in some kind of output and you want to check it against a pre-recorded output.

Comment: Where is the difference between the static create method and a second public constructor that accepts only Bar?

Comment: @Cyril In this artificial, isolated example, absolutely nothing. But in general, there are plenty of advantages (and a few disadvantages) of [using factory methods instead of constructors](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151). It's by no means the way everything should be done, but it's a pretty good way.